# How to upload and download files from Google Drive (using Rest Api v3)

Tags: android, google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

I am using the following java code to upload a file from my Android app to Google Drive using the REST Api v3:

```
String UploadFileToGoogleDrive(String sFullPath, String sFileName, String sParentFolderId) {               
    com.google.api.services.drive.model.File fileMetadata = new com.google.api.services.drive.model.File();
    fileMetadata.setName(sFileName);
    fileMetadata.setParents(Collections.singletonList(sParentFolderId));
    java.io.File filePath = new java.io.File(sFullPath);
    FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(null, filePath);
    try {
        com.google.api.services.drive.model.File file = googleDriveService.files().create(fileMetadata, mediaContent)
                .setFields("id, parents")
                .execute();
        return file.getId();
    } catch (IOException e) {            
        return null;
    }       
}
```

And I use this code to download the file:

```
boolean DownloadFileFromGoogleDrive(String sFileId, String sDestinationPath) {       
    try {
        FileOutputStream oFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(sDestinationPath));
        googleDriveService.files().get(sFileId).executeAndDownloadTo(oFileOutputStream);
        oFileOutputStream.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

The file gets uploaded (apparently) but, when I download it, it is not readable. The size is much smaller, too. I need to upload images and other files like my own app settings (which is not a mime type) that is why I set null in this line:

```
FileContent mediaContent = new FileContent(null, filePath);
```

I have also have tried with "*image/jpeg*" but I got same results. The downloaded file is not readable.

Any ideas of what I am doing wrong? I cannot find much documentation about Google Drive v3 and Android with Java.

Comment: It would be useful to know if you have a file upload issue, a file download issue or both. Take a look at the upload first. Are you sure that the file is being uploaded correctly? Can you take a look at it in the Drive app or online to see if it is ok?

Comment: I am uploading to the AppFolder so I am not able to check it from the web site.

Comment: Right. So, for debugging, upload it to a non-AppData folder to check the logic. I think the logic should be the same except for the specification of a different target folder if I remember correctly.

Comment: What file and mime-type are you trying to upload/download? Did you try using the ["Try his API"](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/create) tool to build the requests?

Comment: No I haven't. Let me take a look at it. I am uploading different file types, for example png files and a copy of my sqllite database.

Comment: I have checked that the files get uploaded correctly. I changed the scope to "drive" (instead of "appdatafolder") and I can verify that the files are uploaded correctly. Something must be wrong in the download code. Any suggestion? This should be extremely easy and there should be tons of examples about something as simple as downloading a file from Drive using an Android app, but it seems that Android is left aside in the documentation

Comment: Solved. I added the solution. The problem was in the DownloadFileFromGoogleDrive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, solved. The problem was in the DownloadFileFromGoogleDrive function:

```
boolean DownloadFileFromGoogleDrive(String sFileId, String sDestinationPath) {       
    try {
        OutputStream oOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(sDestinationPath);
        googleDriveService.files().get(sFileId).executeMediaAndDownloadTo(oOutputStream);
        oOutputStream.flush();
        oOutputStream.close();
        return true
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```